# drop single mysql table from command line

Tags: php, mysql, shell, console

I'm trying to run the following line from my php script:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($table_list);$i++){
        $command1='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' DROP TABLE `'.$table_list[$i].'`';
        exec($command1);
}
```

An array with table names is already created earlier.

Nothing happens, table doesn't get dropped. Of course, exec() is enabled.

When I try to run the following command from console, I just get instructions on how to use the mysql command (just as if I used `mysql -?`):

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME DROP TABLE products
```

I also tried putting table name in quotes, but same thing - no luck.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: since you are using php, why not just use php mysql library to drop table?

Comment: @hawshy to be perfectly honest - I have no idea. The entire script was built more than a year ago and was working just fine until we moved to a new server 2 weeks ago. I think there was a reason it was built this way, but I can't remember...

Comment: I think you should convert to use php drop table script instead.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the problem? Did you figure out how to get mysql called from your exec command?

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is because you havent given proper space

You have this

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME DROP TABLE products
```

and it should be like

```
mysql -h localhost -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASENAME DROP TABLE products
```

see `-h &  -u & -p` have a proper space before and after

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql), you need to use -e / --execute:

> --execute=statement, -e statement Execute the statement and quit. The
>   default output format is like that produced with --batch. See Section
>   4.2.3.1, "Using Options on the Command Line", for some examples. With this option, mysql does not use the history file.

Try the following from the console:
`mysql -h localhost -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -e "DROP TABLE products" DATABASENAME`

Or the fixed up script:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($table_list);$i++){
        $command1='mysql -h '.$mysqlHostName .' -u ' .$mysqlUserName .' -p ' .$mysqlPassword .' -e "DROP TABLE `'.$table_list[$i].'`" '.$mysqlDatabaseName ;
        exec($command1);
}
```

Comment: thank you - this is very close, but still not there. First, I had to remove quotes from table name like this `"DROP TABLE '.$table_list[$i].'"`, otherwise it didn't work. When I run it in php, it does nothing. But, when I echo the command and run that command in console, it works just fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: Use the full path to the mysql binary: `/path/to/mysql -h ...`

Comment: makes no difference. I think it's something related to my server's mysql and can't figure out what. I'm trying to run a simple import, but that's failing too. When I run this command `/usr/bin/mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASENAME < /path/to/directory/products.sql`, it doesn't work. I just get the help text, as if I ran `mysql -?` Do you see anything wrong with that line? I've also tried using mysql w/o path and tried putting file path in quotes. Could it be something with the server?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with that line. If you see the same a -? it means you did not give correct command line options.